Unable to Load Data from Google Apps Script into HTML Interface
I'm developing an add-on for Google Sheets. My requirement is to open an HTML interface to update information, where the initial data from the Google Sheets should be preloaded into the interface fields upon opening.
Current Issue:
The HTML interface opens, but all fields (textboxes, inputs) are empty.
There are no error logs in Google Apps Script.
My Implementation:

loadSettings Function (Apps Script):

function loadSettings() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('title');
  return {
    schoolName: sh.getRange("C5").getValue(),
    examName: sh.getRange("E5").getValue(),
    subject: sh.getRange("H8").getValue(),
    // Other fields...
  };
}

2 Function to Open the Interface openUpdateSettingsDialog:
function openUpdateSettingsDialog() {
  const data = loadSettings();
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('inputUpdateSettings')
    .setWidth(800)
    .setHeight(600)
    .append(`<script>window.onload = function() { fillSettings(${JSON.stringify(data)}); };</script>`);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Update Test Settings');
}


fillSettings Function in HTML:

function fillSettings(data) {
  document.getElementById('schoolName').value = data.schoolName || '';
  document.getElementById('examName').value = data.examName || '';
  document.getElementById('subject').value = data.subject || '';
  // Other fields...
}


HTML Interface:

<input type="text" id="schoolName" />
<input type="text" id="examName" />


Expectation:
When the interface is opened, fields like schoolName and examName should be filled with data from the Google Sheets.
Problem:
The fields remain empty, and no data is displayed.
Questions:

Is there any issue with how I am passing data from Apps Script to the HTML interface?
How can I debug and fix this issue effectively?


loadSetting is undefined. Try using and HtmlTemplate (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template)

data in fillSettings is a string not an object.  Don't stringify.  I would use an htmlTemplate
